# Can open URL HTML

Tags: javascript

Can I check if I can open a URL like **OBLevel://id=18291234** in JavaScript before I link to it?

Thank you!

Comment: Is your question ? How to check if the given URL OBLevel://id=18291234 is a valid URL using JavaScript

Comment: @HatSoft I think he means open it like how `itms://` opens iTunes. This would require some ActiveX to examine the system preferences.

Answer (score 1):

Not with Javascript.  You'd need to know what sort of applications are available on the computer (other than the browser), which isn't something you can know using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a GET with jQuery? If there's a answer, then you know you can use it. Otherwise if it's some obscure protocol or application not supported by jQuery, there's no way to do it.

Experiment!

Comment: This is not an answer, this should be a comment.